# std string vs char performance, best technique to delete parts from the beginning

Tags: c++, performance, string, char, std

well i have to process a large chunk of text, analysing it linear from begin to end. And i wonder what is the better approach for this: using char* or std::string.
while using char* i can alter the pointer to a position further in the string eg.

```
//EDIT later: mallocing some space for text
char str[] = "text to analyse";
char * orig = str;
//process
str += processed_chars; //quite fast
//process again
// later: free(orig);
```

but using string i might have to use std::string::erase - but it create a copy, or move bytes or something (i don't know the actual implementation)

```
string str = "text to analyse";
//process
str = str.erase(0,processed_chars);
```

or is there a way to alter the std::string's hidden pointer?

EDIT: as Sylvain Defresne requested here more code:

```
class tag {
public:
    tag(char ** pch) {
        *pch = strstr(*pch,"<");
        if(pch == NULL) return;

        char *orig = *pch+1;
        *pch = strstr(*pch,">");
        if(pch == NULL) return;
        *pch+=sizeof(char); //moving behind the >

        //process inner tag data

        if(*(*pch-2)!='/'){// not selfclose
            while (!(**pch == '<' && *(*pch+1) == '/')){ //sarch for closing tag
                tag* kid = new tag(pch);
                sublings.push_back(*kid);
            }

            *pch = strstr(*pch,">");
            if(pch == NULL) return;
            *pch+=sizeof(char); //moving behind the >

            //add check if the clothing tag is matching

        }
    }
}
```

i use it for recursive xml-like notation parsing

```
char str[] ="<father><kid /></fatherr>";
char * pch = str;
tag *root = new tag(&pch);
```

this code is ugly as hell, i am just starting with low-level pointer arithmetic and stuff, used visual components till now so don't judge too hard

Comment: Have you tried profiling both approaches to see what the actual impact would be?

Comment: std::string str = "text to analyze"; char const * c = str.c_str() + 5;

Comment: @Mark Loeser: when using `erase`, the matching algorithm becomes superlinear (O(n²), i think).

Comment: Why are you free'ing orig? That would cause a segmentation fault. Typo?

Comment: You did not `malloc` anything, why are you calling `free(orig)`? That line causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @MM, FredOverflow: Typo, lost the slashes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `std::string`, you would probably use `std::string::iterator`. Your code would be:

```
std::string str = "text to analyse";
std::string::iterator iter = str.begin();

// process
iter += processed_chars;
```

Comment: but how do i access the the string from my iter and going further - thats the point of my processing and the reason a alter the pointer int he char version

Comment: `std::string::iterator` is basically a `char*` in disguise (or a little wrapper over it). To read the current char, dereference it `*iter`, this return a reference so you can write to it `*iter = 'a'` ...

Comment: not exaclty what i mean `char foo[] = "lorem ipsum"; foo++; cout << foo;` produces `orem ipsum` and this is what i want so archive here

Comment: You'll have to do `std::string foo = "lorem ipsum"; std::string::iterator it = foo.begin(); ++ it; std::cout << &*it;`.

Comment: but how do i get a std::string starting from there

Comment: You create a new string `std::string substring(iter, str.end());`.

Comment: i've only got `substr(size_t,size_t)`, and wouldn't it create a copy?

Comment: Yes it will, but with `char*`, you'll have to make a copy too in the end if you want to return it (or the caller will have to keep the pointer to the original string and use it to free memory). We will need more information about what usage you want to really help you choose what is best.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you can do with a `char*`, you can do with an `std::string::iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::string::iterator` (look [here](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/begin/)).

`std::string` is not neccassary in such task (but such classes as `std::string` are very useful in other situations).

Comment: Considering that std::string::iterator consists of a `char*` member and a couple of inlined function, I am sure we can strike "almost" from "almost unnoticed". :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson: But if you decide to create `nothrow` method? (if you are sure not to leave the allocated memory) `std::string::iterator` can throw exceptions (I think) (p.s. not sure; to clarify this, we need to see the standard).

Comment: No, the iterators will not throw any exceptions. The only exception you would get is a bad_alloc when initializing the string, and there is not enough memory.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Then you are right `:)`. There is no difference at all.